# I want to add a Relationship between two already existing nodes in Neo4j - how to do that using Spring Data Neo4jRepository?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

The cypher query to perform the above task would be as follows:

> **MATCH** (a:*Buyer*), (b:*Seller*)
> **MERGE** (a) -[:**BUY** {quantity: 150}]-> (b);

I want the equivalent Neo4jRepository function or some equivalent code that can serve the same above purpose. Please post the answer if you know some solution.

*[Updates]*

I have posted an answer below. But I am also expecting some other kind of solutions to this purpose. Please feel free to post alternative solutions as answers.

Answer (score 0):

*One Possible Way*

If we have two Nodes/Entities as `Buyer` and `Stock` as POJO classes in SpringBoot Code, and if we are trying to add a relationship called **[:HAS]** between two such nodes then we can do the following.

```
@Node("Stock")
class Stock
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue(...)
   private Long id;
   
   /* Other attributes here --- */
}

@Node("Buyer")
class Buyer
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue(...)
   private Long id;
   /* Other Attribute Variables Here --- */

   @Relationship(type="HAS")
   private List<Stock> stockList;

   public List<Stock> getStockList()
   {
       return stockList;
   }

   public void setStockList(List stockList)
   {
       this.stockList = stockList;
   }

}
```

So we can do this to create the desired relationship.

```
buyer.getStockList().add(newStock);
buyerRepo.save(buyer);
```

Here `buyerRepo` is the object of a Repository that implements `Neo4jRepository<Buyer, Long>`